# How to get symbolized call-stacks with coredumpctl info?

Tags: systemd, core-dump

I am trying to enable systemd coredumps containing call stacks with function names when printed with `coredumpctl info`, so that I can get a call stack without using gdb and/or `coredumpctl debug` (since my real target has no debugger installed). Thus I want to use only `coredumpctl info`.

Using Fedora 39, I installed the package `tftp-server`, and tested coredumps by starting tftpd (systemctl start tftp), and sending `kill -SEGV` to the process `/usr/sbin/in.tftpd` . I then see that coredumps created that way contain the function names inside the `in.tftpd` process (Fedora enables `minidebuginfo`/`gnu_debugdata` by default).

However, when I do the same thing using a test C file which I compiled with debug symbols, I see that my test coredumps show `n/a` for the function names in my process (I tried with full debug symbols as well as with only `minidebuginfo`/`gnu_debugdata`).

What do I need to do so that my application also generates proper coredumps, like it is doing for binaries installed by Fedora packages?

- Test code (file `test.c`):

  ```C
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <unistd.h>

  int test123()
  {
      printf("test123\n");
      sleep(1);
  }

  int main()
  {
      for (;;) {
          test123();
      }
  }
  ```
- Test Makefile:

  ```
  all:
      gcc ./test.c -o test-with-symbols -g
  ```
- `coredumpctl info` of `in.tftpd` looks good on Fedora (it shows the function name `main` in `in.tftpd`):

  ```shellsession
  $ coredumpctl info 4335
             PID: 4335 (in.tftpd)
             UID: 0 (root)
             GID: 0 (root)
          Signal: 11 (SEGV)
       Timestamp: Mon 2023-11-20 06:07:08 EST (1h 36min ago)
    Command Line: /usr/sbin/in.tftpd -s /var/lib/tftpboot
      Executable: /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
   Control Group: /system.slice/tftp.service
            Unit: tftp.service
           Slice: system.slice
         Boot ID: 954e4f02e86e4f6498987e2e202d0413
      Machine ID: 28dd14ccbe5b46018201dd25d5a60e94
        Hostname: localhost-live
         Storage: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.in\x2etftpd.0.954e4f02e86e4f6498987e2e202d0413.4335.1700478428000000.zst (missing)
         Package: tftp/5.2-41.fc39
        build-id: 438daef3ffb345cc3c791def1ceba465865929f6
         Message: Process 4335 (in.tftpd) of user 0 dumped core.

                  Module in.tftpd from rpm tftp-5.2-41.fc39.x86_64
                  Stack trace of thread 4335:
                  #0  0x00007ffb2640ef8e __select (libc.so.6 + 0x112f8e)
                  #1  0x00005578d0fde699 main (in.tftpd + 0x4699)
                  #2  0x00007ffb2632414a __libc_start_call_main (libc.so.6 + 0x2814a)
                  #3  0x00007ffb2632420b __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.34 (libc.so.6 + 0x2820b)
                  #4  0x00005578d0fdfa15 _start (in.tftpd + 0x5a15)
                  ELF object binary architecture: AMD x86-64
  ```
- `codedumpctl info` of my test binary shows `n/a` instead of function names. I tested this on Fedora 39 and on Ubuntu 22.04 (systemd version 254 on Fedora 39, systemd version 249 on Ubuntu 22.04):

  ```shellsession
  liveuser@localhost-live:~/Downloads/test$ coredumpctl info 8485
             PID: 8485 (test)
             UID: 1000 (liveuser)
             GID: 1000 (liveuser)
          Signal: 11 (SEGV)
       Timestamp: Mon 2023-11-20 07:26:38 EST (54s ago)
    Command Line: ./test
      Executable: /home/liveuser/Downloads/test/test
   Control Group: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-org.gnome.Terminal.slice/vte-spawn-07143dc2-3f50-4778-a60f-e027a4bb85e9.scope
            Unit: user@1000.service
       User Unit: vte-spawn-07143dc2-3f50-4778-a60f-e027a4bb85e9.scope
           Slice: user-1000.slice
       Owner UID: 1000 (liveuser)
         Boot ID: 954e4f02e86e4f6498987e2e202d0413
      Machine ID: 28dd14ccbe5b46018201dd25d5a60e94
        Hostname: localhost-live
         Storage: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.test.1000.954e4f02e86e4f6498987e2e202d0413.8485.1700483198000000.zst (present)
    Size on Disk: 17.9K
         Message: Process 8485 (test) of user 1000 dumped core.

                  Stack trace of thread 8485:
                  #0  0x00007f8a5b4bd127 clock_nanosleep@GLIBC_2.2.5 (libc.so.6 + 0xd9127)
                  #1  0x00007f8a5b4cf9f7 __nanosleep (libc.so.6 + 0xeb9f7)
                  #2  0x00007f8a5b4e1333 sleep (libc.so.6 + 0xfd333)
                  #3  0x0000558c6c9a118a n/a (/home/liveuser/Downloads/test/test + 0x118a)
                  #4  0x0000558c6c9a119f n/a (/home/liveuser/Downloads/test/test + 0x119f)
                  #5  0x00007f8a5b40c14a __libc_start_call_main (libc.so.6 + 0x2814a)
                  #6  0x00007f8a5b40c20b __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.34 (libc.so.6 + 0x2820b)
                  #7  0x0000558c6c9a10a5 n/a (/home/liveuser/Downloads/test/test + 0x10a5)
                  ELF object binary architecture: AMD x86-64
  ```